# How to handle with switching between daylight and standard time in vcalendar?

Tags: php, outlook, vcalendar

The code generated works only in current time zone (daylight or standard time). When I send an meeting Outlook from standard time to Daylight or vice versa, the outlook corrects meeting and moves it by 1 hour forward.

Outlook correct it like this:
This meeting is customized to your current time zone. Originally was created in this time zone: Europe/Prague.

I send meeting - 6.5.2020: 8-9am
but in Outlook is 6.5.2020: 9-10am

Is problem in Outlook or in my code?
Tahk you for any help...

This is script in php (7) that collecting things data from specific xml sources. I need to send them into outlook calendar. We are using outlook 2016 and 365.

```
    function setICalendar(){
  $this->strICalendarClass="\nBEGIN:VCALENDAR\nMETHOD:REQUEST";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nBEGIN:VTIMEZONE\nTZID:Europe/Prague";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nX-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/Prague";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nBEGIN:STANDARD";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nDTSTART:19411001T000000";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nTZOFFSETFROM:0000\nTZOFFSETTO:0000\nTZNAME:Standard Time";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nCET";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nEND:STANDARD";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nBEGIN:DAYLIGHT";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nDTSTART:19860504T000000";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nTZOFFSETFROM:-0200\nTZOFFSETTO:-0100\nTZNAME:Daylight Savings Time";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nCEST";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nEND:DAYLIGHT\nEND:VTIMEZONE";
  $this->strVEvent="\nBEGIN:VEVENT";

nBEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST;
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Prague;
X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/Prague;
BEGIN:STANDARD";
DTSTART:19411001T000000;
TZOFFSETFROM:0000
TZOFFSETTO:0000
TZNAME:Standard Time;
RULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10;
CET;
END:STANDARD;
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT;
DTSTART:19860504T000000;
TZOFFSETFROM:-0200
TZOFFSETTO:-0100
TZNAME:Daylight Savings Time;
RULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3;
CEST;
END:DAYLIGHT;
END:VTIMEZONE;
```

I expect same time in the beginnig and in outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I repair it, like this and all is working.

```
$this->strICalendarClass="\nBEGIN:VCALENDAR\nMETHOD:REQUEST";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nBEGIN:VTIMEZONE\nTZID:Europe/Prague";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/Prague";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nBEGIN:STANDARD";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nDTSTART:19411001T000000";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nTZOFFSETFROM:-0100\nTZOFFSETTO:0000\nTZNAME:Standard Time";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nCET";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nEND:STANDARD";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nBEGIN:DAYLIGHT";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nDTSTART:20140330T030000";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nTZOFFSETFROM:0000\nTZOFFSETTO:+0100\nTZNAME:Daylight Savings Time";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nCEST";
  $this->strICalendarClass.="\nEND:DAYLIGHT\nEND:VTIMEZONE";
```